# Number of right angled triangles given n points

Tags: algorithm

Given *n* points in the xy plane, I need to find the number of right angled triangles that can be formed using these points as vertices. I did come up with a O(n<sup>3</sup>) solution where you take 3 vertices at a time and check if they form a right angled triangle. I wanted to know a more optimal solution for this problem.

Comment: Any constraints for `n`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's requesting an algorithm and has no specific programming issue

Comment: @PhamTrung no. I just want to know the most optimal solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An O(n^2) solution could be something like this:

- Iterating through each point one by one,
- When processing each point, calculate the unit vector that formed by that point and other point in the list; then store them in a HashMap. For each of those vector, calculate the unit vector that formed a right angle with it and look it up in the HashMap.

Comment: Your solution is rather elegant, when considered theoretically. But when you normalize the vectors, you are ignoring the lengths of the vectors. Pythagorean Theorem is based on the lengths of the edges of the right-angled triangles, which means that you do need to consider the lengths as well. And even if you modify your algorithm to handle them, that would impose an increase in the time complexity of the solution you provided.

Comment: @ilim, why would you need the lengths in order to decide if two vectors are perpendicular?

Comment: @ilim you don't need to consider the length I guess :thinking: ? you can use dot product property to calculate.

Comment: @PhamTrung It seems I misunderstood your usage of HashMap. You are correct. I haven't thought on a formal proof, but your algorithm looks like it works.

Comment: @PhamTrung are you store the frequency of each unit vector against it in the HashMap ?

Comment: @shreyansh yup, should be.